# Can a button bar only show certain contents of a Viewstack it is provided?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.6

Is it possible for a ButtonBar to only show some of the navigator contents in the viewstack. Like, say I only want the button bar to display the button for the first two, and not the third?

```
<s:ButtonBar dataProvider="{mainViewStack}"/>
<mx:ViewStack id="mainViewStack">
 <s:NavigatorContent>
 </s:NavigatorContent>
 <s:NavigatorContent>
 </s:NavigatorContent>
 <s:NavigatorContent>
 </s:NavigatorContent>
</mx:ViewStack>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and didn't found native solution. So I wrote next "hack".
Wrote own class that extends NavitagorContent.

ExtNavigatorContent.as

```
public class ExtNavigationContent extends NavigatorContent
{
    public function ExtNavigationContent()
    {
        super();
    }

    private var _includeInBar:Boolean = true;

    public function get includeInBar():Boolean
    {
        return _includeInBar;
    }

    public function set includeInBar(value:Boolean):void
    {
        _includeInBar = value;
        dispatchEvent(new Event("labelChanged"));
    }
}
```

I created new skin for TabBar (in your case it will be ButtonBar). Then, add next in the standard skin (instead of default ButtonBarButton creating):

```
<s:ButtonBarButton includeInLayout="{data.includeInBar}" visible="{data.includeInBar}" buttonMode="true"/>
```

And, at last, declared TabBar/ButtonBar:

```
<s:TabBar id="menu" dataProvider="{viewstack1}" skinClass="design.skins.tabbar.SimpleTabBarSkin"/>
<mx:ViewStack id="viewstack1" width="100%" height="100%">
    <components:ExtNavigationContent includeInBar="false" />
    <components:ExtNavigationContent includeInBar="true" />
    <components:ExtNavigationContent />
</mx:ViewStack>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will try this and give you feedback if it works for me. :) Wish there was a simpler solution though, ah well.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work....I'm just gonna try a different approach to what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, I gave incorrect example. I will update answer. If you will have problems with my solution write me and I will try to help.